# get files off machine in recovery mode

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, virtualbox, boot-failure

I have a virtualbox VM that is broken. It won't boot normally. I don't want to bother trying to fix it but I do want to get some files off it that I need.

If I hold down the shift key I can get to a prompt allowing me to boot into recovery mode and from there I can select the option netroot and I'm in.  I can get to the files on that machine which I need and the internet works (I can run `wget --spider http://example.com` succesfully.) So it seems like I should have everything I need to get the files off. But how? I thought about trying to setup an FTP server but I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on the host and 10.04LT on the client (VM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way would be to enable SSH on your host, then mount a folder via SSH on your VM.

On the host:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
mkdir ~/vm_backup
```

On the VM:

```
apt-get install sshfs
mkdir /mnt/host
sshfs [username]@[host]:/home/[username]/vm_backup /mnt/host
```

*NOTE:*

- Replace [username] with the username on the host.
- Replace [host] with either the IP address or hostname of the host

Then you can just copy everything you need to /mnt/host

When you are done, if you do not want SSH anymore, simply uninstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server
```

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could be of help. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I do this regularly and you don't even have to start the virtual machine itself. The idea is to mount the disk image on your host machine.

To do this, you'll need virtualbox-fuse:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-fuse
```

You can then mount the image using `vdfuse`. Per example, mounting a VDI image (VMDK and al are also supported), as root:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/vdi
$ vdfuse -f /path/to/disk/image.vdi /mnt/vdi
```

In `/mnt/vdi`, you'll have a disk image for each partition and one for the entire disk:

```
$ ls /mnt/vdi
EntireDisk  Partition1  Partition2
```

Mount the partition you want:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/guest
$ mount /mnt/vdi/Partition2 /mnt/guest
```

And that's it. You can now copy your files from `/mnt/guest` to your host machine without any network overhead whatsoever.

It's also useful for a *ton* of other things other than backing up broken VMs. ;-)

Comment: Wow. This is great. I already got the files off the other way, but I agree this is really good to know.